Building a Vue 3 Typescript component library - How to make autocompletion and suggestions work
I'm building a vue component library, only thing I need is to know how to properly set up the types (I think the solution is to do something in the tsconfig.json) so I can get suggestions and autocompletes for the components of that library.
I've made a separated project for the lib and another one to test it, and it is working (with npm link, I can use a component from the lib normally in the test project), but without any suggestions or autocompletion.
A simple way to reproduce the problem would be create a vite project with vue and typescript, using npm create vite@latest and setup the files as I'm doing to test a simple component, then use npm link or install locally with npm i ../path/to/lib/project to test if the suggestions are working.
I've tried a lot of setups in tsconfig.json, package.json, some of the changes actually created the typescript types for the components, but I couldn't make it work anyway...
I'm gonna set up a simple example here of what I have in my lib project, without too much changes to the files.
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        copyPublicDir: false,
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, "lib/main.js"),
            name: "MyLib",
            fileName: "my-lib",
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ["vue"],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

// ---------------------------------------------

// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        /* Bundler mode */
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",

        /* Linting */
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["lib"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

// ---------------------------------------------

// tsconfig.node.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

// ---------------------------------------------

// package.json

{
    "name": "lib",
    "private": false,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs",
    "module": "./dist/my-lib.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/my-lib.js",
            "require": "./dist/my-lib.umd.cjs"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.4.21"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "vite": "^5.2.0",
        "vue-tsc": "^2.0.6"
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

// lib/Foo.vue

<template>
    <div class="p-4 bg-red-500 text-white">
        <p>Foo: {{ foo }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
    foo: string;
}>();
</script>

// ---------------------------------------------

// lib/main.js

import Foo from "./Foo.vue";
export { Foo };


